# "Dictionary" of name equivalency

Tags: python, dictionary, search, time-complexity

I have a list of names in the parenthetical format, e.g. `Adam (Lawrence, Albert), Erwin (Heintz, Edwin, Bro)` etc. Here the names in parentheses are equivalent to the main name (`Adam = Lawrence = Albert`). How can I store this data type so that I can easily access it in both direction. E.g. if I store as an ordinary dictionary (`{'Adam':'Lawrence, Albert'}`) I can access in O(1) the equivalents of `'Adam'`, but to access the equivalents of `'Lawrence'` I have to search all the values in the dictionary. Is there some data type like `{'Adam':'Lawrence':'Albert', 'Erwin':'Heintz':'Edwin':'Bro'}` where I can easily search easily for any equivalency?

Comment: You use a dict to translate -- this is a relatively easy browser search.

Comment: I don't think my question is equivalent to the one you linked. The accepted answer adequately addresses my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy option is to just make a dictionary with all of the options as keys:

```
In [17]: names = ['Adam (Lawrence, Albert)', 'Erwin (Heintz, Edwin, Bro)']

In [18]: d = {}

In [19]: for name_s in names:
    ...:     namelist = name_s.replace(" (", ", ")[:-1].split(", ")
    ...:     for name in namelist:
    ...:         d[name] = namelist
    ...:

In [20]: d
Out[20]:
{'Adam': ['Adam', 'Lawrence', 'Albert'],
 'Lawrence': ['Adam', 'Lawrence', 'Albert'],
 'Albert': ['Adam', 'Lawrence', 'Albert'],
 'Erwin': ['Erwin', 'Heintz', 'Edwin', 'Bro'],
 'Heintz': ['Erwin', 'Heintz', 'Edwin', 'Bro'],
 'Edwin': ['Erwin', 'Heintz', 'Edwin', 'Bro'],
 'Bro': ['Erwin', 'Heintz', 'Edwin', 'Bro']}
```

This should still be relatively memory efficient since each duplicated list points to the same underlying memory location:

```
In [21]: d['Adam'].append("hi")

In [22]: d
Out[22]:
{'Adam': ['Adam', 'Lawrence', 'Albert', 'hi'],
 'Lawrence': ['Adam', 'Lawrence', 'Albert', 'hi'],
 'Albert': ['Adam', 'Lawrence', 'Albert', 'hi'],
 'Erwin': ['Erwin', 'Heintz', 'Edwin', 'Bro'],
 'Heintz': ['Erwin', 'Heintz', 'Edwin', 'Bro'],
 'Edwin': ['Erwin', 'Heintz', 'Edwin', 'Bro'],
 'Bro': ['Erwin', 'Heintz', 'Edwin', 'Bro']}
```

Comment: This is a great answer.